# Gitlab Upgrade deletes postgres database

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I currently have the Gitlab 7.10.0 version setup. I am trying to upgrade the version to 7.13.2 version(The latest at the time of posting this question.)

I am following these steps for the upgrade.

1. Create a backup of the current database, repos & uploads.(Not sure if relevant.)

   sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
2. Download the 7.13.2 Gitlab Omnibus package.
3. Install the Gitlab 7.13.2 Omnibus package.

   sudo dpkg -i gitlab-ce_7.13.2-ce.0_amd64.deb
4. Reconfigure Gitlab

   sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
5. Restart services
   sudo gitlab-ctl restart

All the components start up, but there is a 500 error when I try to access any page and the logs show that the database no longer exists. (database gitlabhq_production does not exist)

I am not sure why this is happening. Am I missing something/are there any other steps to be followed?

Things I have tried:

1. Use the `sudo gitlab-ctl upgrade` command to upgrade. Did not work, after the command completes, Gitlab is still in 7.10.0 version.
2. Create a backup, do a fresh installation of 7.10.0 version, restore the backup & perform the above listed steps. Did not work, logs show that the production database is missing.

Things I am going to try:

1. Try an incremental upgrade(7.10.x -> 7.11.x -> 7.12.x - 7.13.x). Will be posting back the results.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.